# how to display image and description from database in Android

Tags: android, database, layout

hey guys Im starting developing android aplications however this is my problem.

I need to create a list like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv2RU.jpg
as you can see I need the picture, title, description, finally a cursor that leads me to the complete imformation about the selected option.
searching I found tools like linear or table layouts, but Im not sure if that will be the good way to do this.
my database have just that 3 columns: image(path of the picture), name and description
so my question is ¿what will be the best way to display this? Maybe is something really basic, but again... Im starting with android and I love it! is really interesting I need to get in in this world.
Anyway Hope you guys can help me. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a listView here is a good starting point.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Now as far as getting the picture included as well you would probably need to create a custom class that extends listView and then make the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list view with a custom adapter. The adapter should extend the CursorAdapter class for managing data from database.

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html